# Metrcis Users with filter and user-id account is wrong

Tags: google-analytics-api

Since one month, some kind of request send me bad info.

This request curl -H "Authorization: Bearer XXX" "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga/?ids=ga:123456&metrics=ga:users&start-date=2016-10-01&end-date=2016-11-02&filters=ga:pagePath%3D~^/sale/21830(\?|$)"

This specific request with metrics users send me something like 7, but other metrics looks good (4000 for page view, sessions ...), It's don't work only with account with user-id, and without change, this request work 2 week ago

Comment: I have experienced a similar problem with reporting on user metrics with dimensions such as browser being all returning users==1 for user id views using the Google Analytics API (v3 and v4) since early March. I have reported the issue on the Google Issue Tracker [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36775262](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36775262). Unfortunately I do not know of any workaround as yet. You could follow the issue to see if there is any progress.

Comment: According the API changelog https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog the core API calculation of users was updated on March 8th. However your problem @Olivier dates back to Feb. The notes state that "The calculation for Users and Active Users metrics has been updated to more efficiently count users. You may see a small change in your metrics. For more information please see How users are identified for users metrics." however the change for user id views seems quite drastic.